# Python crashed on creating an instance after successfully importing a Sequential model from tensorflow.keras.models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

System information

OS Platform and Distribution: Windows 7
TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): pip install tensorflow-gpu
TensorFlow-gpu version: 2.1.0
Python version: 3.6.7
Installed using virtualenv
CUDA/cuDNN version: v10.1 / v7.6.5
GPU model and memory: Nvidia Geforce GT 630 1GB

I am just a beginner in all of it. 
Now, when I tried instantiating a Sequential model after successfully importing it from tensorflow.keras.models, I got following errors:

```
>>> model = Sequential()

Fatal Python error: Aborted       #Aborted as I enabled faulthandler

Current thread 0x0000153c (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\framework\c_api_util.py", line 46 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\framework\ops.py", line 2809 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\framework\ops.py", line 5370 in _GetGlobalDefaultGraph
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\framework\ops.py", line 5361 in get_default
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\framework\ops.py", line 5778 in get_default_graph
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\keras\backend.py", line 568 in get_default_graph_uid_map
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\keras\backend.py", line 872 in unique_object_name
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1815 in _init_set_name
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 204 in _base_init
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457 in _method_wrapper
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 383 in _init_subclassed_network
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457 in _method_wrapper
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 172 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 146 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 103 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core
\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457 in _method_wrapper
  File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
```

venv in the path is my virtual environment directory.

Unable to figure out what is causing it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @MohamedKaram. But still getting the same problem. And I instantiated my Sequential model in order to add a number of dense and dropout layers afterwards. Like, model.add(Dense(20,  activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

Comment: i used to have lot of problems with TF on virtualenv , what i recommand u is to use Anaconda with the latest TF it will work so much better

Answer (score 0):

you can try doing this :

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(layers='nb_of_layers',name='your_name')
```

Comment: Could you explain why the OP should try this? Why does this fix the problem?

Comment: It was just a suggestion because sometimes it can be problems of importations , but as i told him on comment , its always better to use TF with Anaconda , using it with virtualenv makes so much problems